# How can I solve Memory usage low! compiler error?

Tags: java, memory, compiler-errors

I was trying to parse excel file and got this error:

ERROR 2022-03-10 12:48:49,965 [Service Thread] [] c.p.e.m.s.MemoryDrainWarningService: Memory usage low! Percentage used=0.8969985811058221. Max memory=178978816. Used memory=160543744

The file is only 2 MB, however there is no error with file 1 MB.
My laptop has 16 GB RAM, I tried to restart laptop, Intellij, updated everything, tried to run it with only Intellij open and all other apps closed, still the same problem.
I tried to increase shared build process heap size (Mbytes) but it changed nothing.
Installed different SDK, with the same result.
Do yo u have any other ideas to solve this problem?

Comment: What you have shown is not a compiler error.  What *software* are you using to get this runtime error message?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was solved by installing Intellij 2020.3 version (previously used the newest one).